# Mostrar una lista de nombres en una columna de la tabla, utilizando un modelo como la lista, con MVC.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Controlador. Aquí estoy llenando la lista con los nombres y id

```
List<NombreProductosMaster> listProductos = new List<NombreProductosMaster> ();

var listaA = (from x in model.EtiquetasProduccion
                                  group x by new
                                  { x.EspeciePresentacionId, x.Producto} into g
                                  select new
                                  {
                                      EspeciePresentacion = g.Key.EspeciePresentacionId,
                                      ProductoNombre = g.Key.Producto,
                                      Rep = g.Count(),
                                  }).ToList();

foreach (var x in listaA)
{
 listProductos.Add(new NombreProductosMaster { Producto = x.ProductoNombre, EspeciePresentacionId =    x.EspeciePresentacion.Value });
}
```

Modelo. En el modelo NombreProductosMaster con el controlador anterior me llena bien los datos, pero la lista que se encuentra dentro de ProduccionEncajonadoViewModel llega null.

```
public class ProduccionEncajonadoViewModel
    {
        #region [Datos Embalaje]

        public int? EmbalajeId { get; set; }
        public int? AlmacenId { get; set; }
        public int? CamaraId { get; set; }
        public int? TipoProduccionId { get; set; }
        public List<NombreProductosMaster> Manual { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public class NombreProductosMaster
    {
        public string Producto { get; set; }
        public int? EspeciePresentacionId { get; set; }
    }
```

La vista. Aquí estoy llenando la columna con la lista

```
<td>
       @foreach (var presentacion in Model.Manual)
       {
           @presentacion.Producto
       }
</td>
```

¿Qué estoy mal o cómo debería hacerlo?

Comment: Debes mostrar más código, no se alcanza a apreciar nada con el que pusiste

Comment: Ese eso todo el proceso que llevo para mostrar los datos de una lista en una columna de la tabla.

Comment: Puedes ver que en el controlador lleno una lista para el modelo NombreProductosMaster, entonces al declararla dentro de ProduccionEncajonadoViewModel como una lista y tratar de usarla en la vista, los datos llangan null.

Comment: Y como la mandas a la vista?? no está esa parte. Lo que no logro cuadrar es que tu llenas NombreProductosMaster pero el model recibe ProduccionEncajonadoViewModel. Entonces si algo llega null el problema puede estar en alguna instanciación que falta

Comment: La vista esta usando el modelo ProduccionEncajonadoViewModel, es una vista parciar que se llena con los datos de ese modelo, entonces como tiene una lista Manual, quiero mostrar esa lista. entonces yo estoy llenando  NombreProductosMaster para posteriormente usarlo. Pero no se si es la forma correcta de hacerlo.

Comment: Así como lo dices claro que está correcto, pero obviamente algo falla. Lo mejor es que coloques la función del controller completa

Comment: O como podria llenar esa lista para poder usarla en la vista?

Comment: Así como dices puedes enviar una lista a la vista, lo otro es usar viewbag. Pero te insisto, colocal la función del controller completa. Mira que no quiero quedarme con la duda

Comment: No puedo poner todo el codigo dek controlador, es extenso, pero retorna un modelo de encajonadoViewModel, pero dentro de ese modelo se encuentra ProduccionEncajonadoViewModel como una lista que regresa la lista de NombreProductosMaster